# Problem with using the State variable in google api + Django

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to add the ability to save files to google disk to the django application. 
I took as a basis an example from the official documentation written in flask [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

```
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

import os
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
cred = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'credentials.json')
```

Function for upload file:

```
def file_to_drive(request, import_file=None):

    state = request.session['state']
    if state is None:
        authorize(request)
    else:
        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
          cred, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
        flow.redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback"
        authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
        flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
        credentials = flow.credentials

        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
        file_metadata = {
            'name': 'My Report',
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
        }
        media = MediaFileUpload(import_file,
                                mimetype='text/html',
                                resumable=True)
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                            media_body=media,
                                            fields='id').execute()
        print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
    return (f"https://docs.google.com/document/d/{file.get('id')}/edit")
```

And function for user authorization

```
def authorize(request):

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      cred, scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback"
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      access_type='offline',
      include_granted_scopes='true')
    request.session['state'] = state
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorization_url)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('oauth2callback', authorize, name='authorize'),
path('to_drive', file_to_drive, name='file_to_drive'),
```

In function `file_to_drive` searching for the value of the state parameter from the session, if it is not found, the `authorize` function is called. 
In the end, I get a message

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

Error traseback looks like

```
  File "/home/y700/projects/CV/cv-base/ems/base/utils.py", line 119, in file_to_drive
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 263, in fetch_token
    self.client_config['token_uri'], **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 208, in fetch_token
    state=self._state)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 203, in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 268, in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise MismatchingStateError()
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
[13/Sep/2019 13:19:52] "GET /to_drive HTTP/1.1" 500 98701
```

the error is caused by a string

```
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line of code:

```
authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
```

It did work for flask but gave troubles in Django.
The problem is in encoding of the URL. I tried different encoders but they didn't worked. So I encoded the code using string manipulation.

```
  #encoding link
  link = request.build_absolute_uri()
  link = str(link)
  s = link.index("code=")
  cut0 = link[0:s+2]
  cut1 = link[s+2:len(link)]
  cut1 = cut1.replace("/","%2F")
  final = cut0+cut1
  authorization_response = final
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  credentials = flow.credentials
  # Store credentials
  # request.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
  # print(request.session['credentials'])

  credentials_dict = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  # print(credentials_dict)

  credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    credentials_dict["token"],
    refresh_token = credentials_dict["refresh_token"],
    token_uri = credentials_dict["token_uri"],
    client_id = credentials_dict["client_id"],
    client_secret = credentials_dict["client_secret"],
    scopes = credentials_dict["scopes"])

  service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    file_metadata = { ......
```

Store credentials in DB instead of Session.